# How to add collapse button in ion card header?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

How to add collapse button in ion card header? I was trying:

```
  <div class="list card">
    <div class="item item-divider">Пошук
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory ion-star"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body">

      <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
          Звіти
        </div>
        <select mobi_select_picker=true data-role="none">
          <option value=''>Всі</option>
          <option value='1'>Осаго</option>
          <option value='2'>Каско</option>
        </select>
      </label>         

    </div>
  </div>
```

i want something like that:

http://s18.postimg.org/d9si9ixjd/toggle_card.png

But it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Your HTML is not complete and the question isn't precise. Could you share a screenshot/design so we could help you with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to add an anchor tag with icon inside the `item-divider` div.

```
<a href="#" class="item-icon-right">
    <i class="icon ion-minus"></i>
</a>
```

So now your HTML will look like:

```
<div class="list card">
    <div class="item item-divider">Пошук
        <a href="#" class="item-icon-right">
            <i class="icon ion-minus"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
                Звіти
            </div>
            <select mobi_select_picker=true data-role="none">
                <option value=''>Всі</option>
                <option value='1'>Осаго</option>
                <option value='2'>Каско</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/keval5531/pen/YPBgVa) and tell me if that is what you wanted.

Comment: I was wondering if clicking on - icon can collapse entire card showing only Header and the - icon toggles to + icon giving an option to expand the card to show all items like before?

Comment: @SagarMody Yes, you are right, standard collapse/expand functionality.